# getMimeTypeFromExtension returns null when I pass "json" as extension

Tags: android, json, mime-types

The following code returns null

```
MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension("json");
```

I've tried it with other formats like mp4, png, etc... and it works fine but fails to work for json.

I've also tried `URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromName` and got null as well.

So how can I get the mime type of a json which I'm expecting it to be `"application/json"`?

**Temporary Solution**

```
public static final String MIME_TYPE_JSON = "application/json";

private static final String EXTENSION_JSON = "json";

@Nullable
public static String getMimeType(final String path) {
    // StringUtil is my own util but you can use Guava for the same result
    String extension = StringUtil.getExtension(path).toLowerCase();
    return extension.equals(EXTENSION_JSON) ?
                MIME_TYPE_JSON : MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension(extension);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Android does not support "json" (and "js" for javascript extension), check the source code [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore/+/android-5.0.2_r1/luni/src/main/java/libcore/net/MimeUtils.java). and [see](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore/+/android-5.0.2_r1/luni/src/main/java/libcore/net/MimeUtils.java#472) the method that you are calling, it will return null if the given extension is not listed in the defined set of content type map.

Answer (score 0):

Modified answer.

So i tested few things apparently nothing works other then urlConnection.getContenttype . I am adding a example i created. 
Cart.java

```
package com.plumtestongo.sample;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.webkit.MimeTypeMap;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

public class Cart extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        new background().execute();
    }

    private class background extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,String>{

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            String mime1;
            String mime2;
            String mime3;
            String mime4;
            boolean hasMime;

            Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://192.168.0.6:3000/jo.json").buildUpon().build();
            try {
                URL url = new URL(uri.toString());
                URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
                urlConnection.connect();
                mime1 = URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromName("jo.json");
                mime2 = urlConnection.getContentType();
                mime3 = URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
                mime4 = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension(MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(url.toString()));
                hasMime = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().hasMimeType("application/json");
                Log.i(Cart.this.getClass().getName(),"Have extension we are looking for:"+hasMime);
                Log.i(Cart.this.getClass().getName(),"From Name: Correct mime type is:"+mime1);
                Log.i(Cart.this.getClass().getName(),"From Content type: Correct mime type is:"+mime2);
                Log.i(Cart.this.getClass().getName(),"From Input stream type: Correct mime type is:"+mime3);
                Log.i(Cart.this.getClass().getName(),"From Extension type: Correct mime type is:"+mime4);

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }


    }

}
```

I am hosting node.js web server(express.js) on my local machine. 
app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
const port = 3000;
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.send('hello world')
});
var stat = express.static('./public');
app.use(stat);
app.listen(port, function () {
    console.log('magic happening at:' + port);
});
```

In home dir I have a public folder which contains a json file(jo.json) and server sends this file when requested.
jo.json

```
{
    name: "inder"
    , age: 24
}
```

and log cat:

```
06-21 11:25:38.581 6441-6493/com.plumtestongo.sample I/com.plumtestongo.sample.Cart: Have extension we are looking for:false
06-21 11:25:38.581 6441-6493/com.plumtestongo.sample I/com.plumtestongo.sample.Cart: From Name: Correct mime type is:null
06-21 11:25:38.581 6441-6493/com.plumtestongo.sample I/com.plumtestongo.sample.Cart: From Content type: Correct mime type is:application/json
06-21 11:25:38.581 6441-6493/com.plumtestongo.sample I/com.plumtestongo.sample.Cart: From Input stream type: Correct mime type is:null
06-21 11:25:38.581 6441-6493/com.plumtestongo.sample I/com.plumtestongo.sample.Cart: From Extension type: Correct mime type is:null
```

use   urlConnection.getContenttype which is the only method working. Thank you

Comment: how can that be more accurate when an exact string comparison happens in the method mentioned in the question ?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLConnection.html#guessContentTypeFromStream(java.io.InputStream)

As document stats some http server can return wrong  type.it can be better approach to get mine type from bytes .

Comment: that makes sense

Comment: still returns null

Comment: I have modified my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This was a bug in Android that was fixed in Android Q Beta.